# Hibernate specific annotations only

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, annotations

I been reading alot on hibernate.

Hibernate Annotations implement the JPA annotations, plus have additional annotations for Hibernate specific features.

Searched alot but couldn't find anything mentioning Hibernate specific annotation. Someone tell me what are Hibernate specific annotation except those of JPA 2.0 annoattion please?

Answer (score 1):

Well I can think of 
[Hibernate Named Queries](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/)

Also here are the [Hibernate Extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec)

Answer (score 1):

You can find lot of information about Hibernate specific annotation in

Beginning Hibernate: From Novice to Professional (Beginning: from Novice to Professional) book.